# dimension of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

How do we find out the dimension of the set of possible values of a vector from a set of linear equations in general? For example, the set of values taken by vector $x=[x_1, \dots, x_n] \in R^n$ that satisfy

$$
x_i = a + b_i , \forall i =1,\dots, n,
$$
$a$ and $b_i$ can vary in $R$, 
$$
\sum_i b_i = 0
$$

I.e. how do we find the dim of the subspace
$\{x \in R^n | \exists a, b_1,\dots, b_n \in R, \text{ such that } x_i = a + b_i , \forall i =1,\dots, n, \sum_i b_i = 0 \}$?

Answer (score 2):

The subspace you have given is an affine subspace of dimension $n-1$, namely
$$S = \{\vec a + x | e^T x=0, \ x\in\mathbb R^n\}$$
Where $e = (1,1,\ldots, 1)^T \in \mathbb R^n$ and $\vec a = a\cdot e$.

---

For a set of linear equations $Ax = b$ with $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}, b\in\mathbb R^m$, the dimension of the admissible subspace is $n - \mathop{\rm rank} A$ if it is nonempty.

Comment: @Alice Yes, that's what I have written a solution for.

Comment: @AlexR: I think the subspace given is only a subset of $S$. precesely it's the single point $(a+b_i)_i$.

Comment: @Mohamed Read again; $b$ is allowed to vary. It's all points $\vec a+b$ where $b$ satisfies $\sum_i b_i = e^T b = 0$, wich is exactly what I wrote.

Comment: "For a set of linear equations $Ax = b$ with $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}, b\in\mathbb R^m$, the dimension of the admissible subspace is $n - \mathop{\rm rank} A$ if it is nonempty." What I was asking is an example of: given matrix $A$, what is the dim of $\{x | x = A c, \forall c \in R^m\}$. Isn't the dim the rank of $A$? How about the example in my post?

Comment: Thank you AliceR. I use this expalnation to give an other answer.

Comment: @Alice In that case you want the dimension of the range of $A$. This is, as you noted, equal to $\mathop{\rm rank} A$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $b$ and $a$ are allowed to vary (thank's AliceR), we can write the equation of $S$ as:
$$X=Ab+\alpha$$  where: $$A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1&\cdots&0&0\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots \\0&\cdots&1&0\\-1&\cdots&-1&0 \end{array} \right) \; \text{and}\; \alpha = \left(\begin{array}{c}a \\ \vdots \\a \end{array} \right)$$

The dimension of $S$ is the rank of $A$ , thus: $n-1$.